# Mercurial seems ignoring its config .hgrc, why?

Tags: mercurial

I preconfigured a login/pass to my `.hgrc` data, despite that the mercurial ignores it:

```
[auth]
becpg.prefix = https://becpg.fr/hg/becpg-community
becpg.username = read-only
becpg.password = read-only
```

Trying to clone it, I get this:

```
$ hg clone https://becpg.fr/hg/becpg-community
http authorization required for https://www.becpg.fr/hg/becpg-community
realm: beCPG repositories
user:
```

Giving him the login and the password manually, it is accepted without any problem.

Stracing the mercurial process, I find that yes, it finds my `.hgrc` in my home, and reads it in:

```
15751 open("/home/myusername/.hgrc", O_RDONLY) = 3
15751 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=112, ...}) = 0
15751 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=112, ...}) = 0
15751 lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)             = 0
15751 lseek(3, 0, SEEK_CUR)             = 0
15751 fstat(3, {st_mode=S_IFREG|0600, st_size=112, ...}) = 0
15751 read(3, "[auth]\nbecpg.prefix = https://becpg.fr/hg/becpg-community\nbecpg.username = read-only\nbecpg.password = read-only\n", 4096) = 112
15751 read(3, "", 4096)                 = 0
15751 close(3)                          = 0
```

What could be the reason?

Comment: wrong password?

Comment: @planetmaker Thanks, but not. Giving it manually, it is accepted without any problem. I inserted it into the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ hg clone https://becpg.fr/hg/becpg-community
http authorization required for https://www.becpg.fr/hg/becpg-community
```

You try to clone from `becpg.fr`, then the authorization asks for `www.becpg.fr`.

I believe you are being redirected.
Try this:

```
[auth]
becpg.prefix = www.becpg.fr/hg/becpg-community
becpg.username = read-only
becpg.password = read-only
```

Comment: Eagle eye. Tyvm!